# Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 disable default base URI pattern value (resources)

Tags: java, weblogic12c, jersey-client, servlet-mapping

Pre-requsitions:

1. WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0
2. Common Java web-application deployed
3. Started using Jersey **client** library

Issue:

Right after that **/resources/** URI has been mapped/handled by (embedded) WebLogic JAX-RS/Jersey servlet handler.

WL mapping issue:

[image]

Googling shown this (pretty similar):

- [Automatic Jax-RS registration in Weblogic 12.2.1 when adding eclipselink artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146254/automatic-jax-rs-registration-in-weblogic-12-2-1-when-adding-eclipselink-artifac)

and

- https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/RESTF/deploy-restful-service.htm#RESTF191

From the Oracle's docs:

> ***<servlet-mapping>**
>
> ...If not specified, one of the following values are used, in order of precedence:
>
> **@ApplicationPath** annotation value defined in the javax.ws.rs.core.Application subclass.
>
> ...
>
> The value **resources**. This is the **default base URI pattern** for
>   RESTful Web service applications.
>
> ...
>
> If both the **<servlet-mapping>** and @ApplicationPath are
>   specified, the **<servlet-mapping>** takes precedence.*

I do not need REST services and default mapping at all - just want to use **Jersey client only**. After trying different options I haven't succeed with any solution.

Explicitly added configuration in `web.xml`  *(tried for both JAX-RS 1.1 and 2.0 vesrions), without implementing any endpoints, as use only Jersey client with setting **<servlet-mapping>***:

**web.xml**

```
<!--WebLogic Jersey Configuration-->
<servlet>
    <display-name>WL Jersey Configuration</display-name>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <!--<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>-->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.wls.server.monitoring.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*In addition updated* **weblogic.xml**:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        ...
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

It did not help. Any ideas on how to disable/override this *default* behaviour of WLS 12.2.1.0.0? Or maybe I've missed or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE. The issue fixed now.

**1. weblogic.xml changed**:

```
    <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>ch.qos.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>            
        <!--Jax-RS-->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
        <!--Jersey 2.0-->
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- wls -->
        <wls:package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.api.client.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.internal.api.client.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.dispatch.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.monitoring.util.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <!-- apis -->
        <wls:resource-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:resource-name>
        <!-- jersey -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:resource-name>
        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.jvnet.hk2.tiger_types.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

i.e.:

- **<wls:prefer-application-resources>** section was added.
- in **<wls:prefer-application-packages>** section next blocks were added:

  ```
    <!--Jax-RS--> and below
    <!--Jersey 2.0--> and below
    <!-- wls --> and below
  ```

**2. Added endpoint config**:

```html
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("path.to.the.package");
    }
}
```

**3. Added dependency to pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**4. web.xml servlet config**:

```
    <!--WebLogic Jersey Configuration-->
<servlet>
    <display-name>WL Jersey Configuration</display-name>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>path.to.the.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[This link helped a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361136/using-jersey-2-x-web-service-on-weblogic-12-1-1)

P.S. Later using of Jackson 2.X library on WLS was similarly fixed (just added proper class to the **<wls:prefer-application-packages>** section)

Comment: I faced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088493/jersey-stopped-working-with-injectionmanagerfactory-not-found with suggested changes worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Solution shared by Taras is working fine, i had to add below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with weblogic 12.2.1 and com.sun.jersey, I have updated to org.glassfish.jersey version 2.26

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In my web.xml file I updated my servlet as following:

```
<servlet>        
    <servlet-name>your servlet name</servlet-name>        
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            path.to.rest.resources
        </param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
</servlet>
```

No other change was needed, and the issue was resolved. Hope can be helpful